# what is the difference between setting up the background color of a button directly an through solid color brush in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to set the background color of a button which i had defined in a resource dictionary. 
but when i am trying to use the below code it is not reflecting.

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource Seat}" Name="A2"  Background="{Binding  Source={StaticResource  LimeGreen111}}" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50"/>
```

but wheni use through `SolidColorBrush` it was working as expected.

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource Seat}" Name="A1"  MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50">
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource AliceBlue1}"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

what is the difference between these two can any one explain

Comment: Can you add your StaticResource  content. this may be because AliceBlue1 setter is not `solidcolorbrush`

Answer (score 2):

Provided that `LimeGreen111` actually is a `Brush` resource, you could use it like this to set the `Background` of a `Button`:

```
<Button ...  Background="{StaticResource LimeGreen111}" />
```

But you cannot set the `Background` property of a `Button` to a `Color` resource because the type of the `Background` property is `System.Windows.Media.Brush`.